# What is the best method to update GUI based on calculations in another thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, user-interface

I want to draw a ball on a JPanel. But the Ball object must not depend on the GUI. It has to change it's position independently. So my Ball class is:

```
class Ball implements Runnable{
   int x=0;
   @Override
   public void run() {
       while(true){
           x+=10;
           x%=100;
       }
   }   
}
```

My JPanel is:

```
class Plane extends JPanel{
    Ball b;
    Plane(Ball b){
        this.b=b;  
    }   
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        g.fillArc(b.x, 10, 10,10,0,360);
    }
}
```

Now how can I change my GUI when b's position change. I can't keep instance of Plane in Ball class. Should I use Swing.Timer class inside Plane class to update GUI or should I make Plane class also a thread? Is there any better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to separate model (Ball) from Thread where the Ball is changed. Your thread can keep a reference to panel where getBall() method exists and use the method to change Ball's position. Then the thread can use

```
SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(
   runnable which update ball and calls panel.repaint() to reflect the ball changes
)
```

the the thread can just sleep for 10msec

Comment: Ok, you if Ball is run in a thread the SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait containing panel.repaint() could be called right after X position change. Or you can try to organize listener as it was suggested by @TrevorBrown but anyway repaint() must be called in Event Dispatching Thread

Answer (score 0):

You could always add a little indirection

```
interface BallUpdateListener {
    public void ballUpdated (Ball b);
}

class Plane extends JPanel implements BallUpdateListener {
    Ball b;
    Plane(Ball b){
        this.b=b;
        this.b.addListener (this);
    }   
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        g.fillArc(b.x, 10, 10,10,0,360);
    }
}

class Ball implements Runnable{
    int x=0;
    List<BallUpdateListener> listeners = new ArrayList<> ();
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(true){
            x+=10;
            x%=100;
            for (BallUpdateListener listener : listeners) {
                ballUpdated (this);
            }
        }
    }
    public void addListener (BallUpdateListener listener) {
        listeners.add (listener);
    }
}
```

Keep in mind this puts the control of updates in the hands of the Ball class. For some problems, this is the right kind of approach. For others, this is a decidedly bad approach. It really depends on your constraints.

Comment: That Ball object obviously must run in a separate thread.  In that case, you have the Ball thread calling `g.fillArc(...)`, and that is not allowed.  All calls that modify Swing objects must come from the Swing Event Dispatch Thread (EDT).  You can fix it by using `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(...)` to ask the EDT thread to call your `BallUpdateListeners`.